# Is there a windows secure persistent storage API?

Tags: c++, windows, security, isolatedstorage

I have an application written in unmanaged C++, that needs to store some binary data on disk.  The data needs to be persistent and I cannot write to a file that can be deleted easily due to security constrains.  Also, the data can be larger than allowed or recommended for Windows Registry.

Is there any windows API or service interface that allows for persistent secure storage?  Ideally, I would like to set up an authentication mechanism, and request to write data (I don't need to know where) and read it back later on, perhaps after restart.

Your help is much appreciated (let me know if you need more details)

Comment: A little more detail on who you're trying to prevent from doing what might help. For example, who's trying to delete the data? The application's user?  Other system users? Is privacy a concern etc....

Comment: Everything persistent is a file on disk at the end of the day. Where do you think registry is stored? Write your data to a file, set ACL to taste.

Comment: Thanks.  I am trying to prevent users from deleting the file data (if I write to a file).  The data in the file can be accessed from certain applications only.

ACL seems interesting, but is there a way to prevent acccess based on applications, i.e. I am interested in making sure that the sensitive data (where ever or however it is stored) can only be accessed by certain applications only?

Comment: Trying to prevent a user from deleting a file that they own is I suspect bound to fail. If it's data that doesn't change at all, then have it owned by a different user and use ACLs to restrict / allow access as appropriate. Just remember that write access will allow them to blank the file.

Comment: If you can run your application as a different user, you might be able to use ACL.  If the user can get admin rights, the user will always be able to delete "your" data (even in the registry).

Comment: So you upgrade your app to v1.1, which by definition is a different executable, and now you suddenly can't read your "own" files anymore? No, this is a classic XY problem.

Answer (score 1):

No, not in the sense that you're looking for. Windows, like most Operating Systems, bases its security model on users instead of applications. If a user can do X with your program, it's because the user has the right to do X. That also means he has that right in any other program, including Explorer.EXE.